# How do I show that $\ell^{\infty}$ is a normed linear space?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

How do I show that $\ell^{ \infty}$ is a normed linear space,
where $\ell^{ \infty}$ is define as $$\|\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\|_{\ell^\infty}=\sup_{1 \leq k \leq \infty} |a_k|?$$
There are three properties that I need to check in order for this to be a normed linear space. Nonnegativity, positive homogeneity, and the triangle inequality.

I am having trouble working with the supremum. Any idea will be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: If you know it is a Banach space, then it is already a normed linear space. Do you want to prove that $l^{\infty}$ is a Banach space?

Comment: no i want to prove it is a norm space, i just want to practice my lp space. i stumble on this problem and i am having a difficulty solving it

Comment: **Hint**: For any $n$, one has $$|a_n+b_n|\le |a_n|+|b_n|\le \sup|a_n|+\sup|b_n|.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the triangle inequality, suppose that $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}\in \ell^{\infty}$. For each index $n$ we have
$$|a_n+b_n|\leq |a_n|+|b_n|\leq \sup_{m}|a_m|+\sup_m|b_m|=\|a\|_{\infty}+\|b\|_{\infty}.$$
Then taking the supremum over all $n$ shows that
$$ \|a+b\|_{\infty}\leq \|a\|_{\infty}+\|b\|_{\infty}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Well begin by noticing that for $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $(x_n),(y_n)\in \ell^\infty$ you have that $(ax_n+by_n)$ is bounded, therefore it belongs in $\ell^\infty$ as well.

For $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ to be a norm, check that it is non-negative and $\|x_n\|_{\infty}$ becomes zero only when $(x_n)=0$.

$\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ also satisfies $\|ax_n\|_{\infty}=|a|\|x_n\|_{\infty}$ and use the triangle inequality for the absolute value to show that  $\|x_n+y_n\|_{\infty}\leq \|x_n\|_{\infty}+\|y_n\|_{\infty}$. These prove $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is a norm on $\ell^\infty$.

Answer (score -2):

Let $(a_n),(b_n) \in \ell^\infty$ Then we have for each $k$:

$$|a_k+b_k| \le |a_k|+|b_k| \le ||(a_n)||_\infty+||(b_n)||_\infty.$$

This shows that $(a_n+b_n) \in \ell^\infty$ and that

$$||(a_n+b_n)||_\infty \le ||(a_n)||_\infty+||(b_n)||_\infty.$$

Comment: The double bars for a norm are typeset with `\|`.  Or, if you want to get fancy, you can use `\Vert` (or, even more fancy, to keep the spacing on the left and right correct, `\lVert` and `\rVert`).  For example `\lVert x_n \rVert` gives $\lVert x_n \rVert$.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but your response pinged me.  Were I to guess, it is because you answered a low-quality duplicate question with an improperly typeset answer (which is also incorrect, though that might be due to a typo---I am not entirely sure what $n)||_{\infty}$ is supposed to mean).

Comment: Ooops, an edit will follow.